# Filter table rows based on JavaScript calculation output

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to filter rows in the following table based on the output of a JavaScript calculation.

I need the output of:

```
var loantovalue = x / h * 100;
```

to filter rows if the value of `loantovalue` is more than the value of `<td class="ltv">`.

I am not really sure how to go about doing this? Any help would be appreciated please.

I filter the data elsewhere using checkboxes, and use this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#type :checkbox").click(function() {
$("td").parent().hide();
$("#type :checkbox:checked").each(function() {
  $("." + $(this).val()).parent().show();
});`
```

So I guess I need to do something similar to the output of `loantovalue`?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#type :checkbox").click(function() {
    $("td").parent().hide();
    $("#type :checkbox:checked").each(function() {
      $("." + $(this).val()).parent().show();
    });
  });
  $("#fee :checkbox").click(function() {
    $("td").parent().hide();
    $("#fee :checkbox:checked").each(function() {
      $("." + $(this).val()).parent().show();
    });
  });
});

var repayment = function() {

};
window.onload = function() {
  document.repaymentcalc.homevalue.onchange = repayment;
  document.repaymentcalc.loanamount.onchange = repayment;
  document.repaymentcalc.numberpayments.onchange = function() {
    $('#years').html(this.value + ' years');
  };
  makeSomething();
};

function makeSomething() {
  $('tbody tr').each(function(idx, row) {
    var $row = $(row);
    var initialRateCell = $row.find('td')[2];
    var repaymentCell = $row.find('td')[7];
    var rate = parseFloat($(initialRateCell).html());
    var repaymentVal = computeRepayment(rate);
    $(repaymentCell).html(repaymentVal.repayment);
  });
}
$("#myForm :input").change(function() {
  makeSomething();
});

function computeRepayment(rate) {
  var x = parseInt(document.repaymentcalc.loanamount.value, 10);
  var y = parseInt(rate * 100, 10) / 120000;
  var z = parseInt(document.repaymentcalc.numberpayments.value, 10) * 12;
  var h = parseInt(document.repaymentcalc.homevalue.value, 10);

  var repayment = y * x * Math.pow((1 + y), z) / (Math.pow((1 + y), z) - 1);

  var loantovalue = x / h * 100;

  $('#ltv').text('Loan to Value: ' + loantovalue.toFixed(2) + '%');

  var year = z / 12;
  return {
    repayment: '£' + repayment.toFixed(2),
    loantovalue: loantovalue,
    year: year
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>

<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

</head>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form name="repaymentcalc" id="myForm" action="">

    <h3>Mortgage Needs</h3>

    <p>Home Value £<input type="number" id="homevalue" value="250000" style="width: 75px"></p>

    <p>Loan Amount £<input type="number" id="loanamount" value="200000" style="width: 75px"></p>

    <p id="ltv">Loan to Value: 80.0%</p>

<section id="type">

  <p id="Mortgage Type">Mortgage Type</p>
  <input type="checkbox" name="type" value="t2" id="t2" checked/>2yr Fixed<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="type" value="t3" id="t3" checked/>3yr Fixed<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="type" value="t5" id="t5" checked/>5yr Fixed<br>

</section>

<section id="fee">

  <p id="Fee">Fee</p>
  <input type="checkbox" name="fee" value="fee" id="fee" checked/>Fee<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="fee" value="nofee" id="nofee" checked/>No Fee<br>

</section>

    Term <input type="range" id="numberpayments" value="25" min="1" max="40" style="width: 75px"> <p id="years" style="display:inline-block;"> 25 years</p>

</form>

<table id="mortgagetable">
    
<thead>

<tr class="producthd"><th class="lenderhd">Lender</th><th class="typehd">Mortgage Type</th><th class="initialratehd">Initial Rate (%)</th><th class="rateshd">Reversion Rate (%)</th><th class="rateshd">Overall APR (%)</th><th class="feehd">Product Fee (£)</th><th class="ltvhd">Maximum LTV (%)</th><th class="repaymenthd">Initial Repayment</th><th class="applylinkhd"></th></tr>

</thead>

<tbody>

<tr class="product"><td class="lender"></td><td class="t2">2yr Fixed</td><td class="initialrate">1.29</td><td class="rates">4.74</td><td class="rates">4.3</td><td class="fee">999</td><td class="ltv">60</td><td class="repayment"></td></td></tr>
<tr class="product"><td class="lender"></td><td class="t2">2yr Fixed</td><td class="initialrate">1.39</td><td class="rates">4.24</td><td class="rates">3.9</td><td class="fee">1495</td><td class="ltv">60</td><td class="repayment"></td><td class="applylink"></td></tr>

</tbody>

</table>
```

Comment: Some clarifications: 1. you want to show only those values whose maximum ltv is greater than loan to value. Right? 2. When do you want the filter to be applied - as soon as the value(s) of home/loan value changes?

Comment: Yes that's right, I want to only show rows where the maximum ltv is equal or more than the value of `var loantovalue`. And I would like this to happen as the value change if possible please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In document ready function add the following code:

```
FilterByMaxLTV();
function FilterByMaxLTV() {

    $("#mortgagetable tbody tr").each(function () {

        var l = parseFloat($('#loanamount').val());
        var h = parseFloat($('#homevalue').val());
        var loneToValue = parseFloat((l/h)*100).toFixed(2);
        $('#ltv').text('Loan to Value: ' + loneToValue + '%');

        //Get the number from the right td.
        var x = parseFloat($(this).find(".ltv").text());
        console.log(x);
        if(x>loneToValue){
            $(this).hide();
        }
        else{
            $(this).show();
        }
    });
}

$('#homevalue,#loanamount').change(function(){
    FilterByMaxLTV();
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/taleebanwar/a6oe6j4r/1/)

What we are doing here is that we have created one function to filter the values. And we are calling the same function on page load (document ready), and on textbox value change.

Note: The calculation can be wrong. Similarly I may have put the wrong sign (less than/ greater than)

Also refer [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/taleebanwar/a6oe6j4r/2/) - here the keyup function is used instead of change function to make it much more dynamic

Comment: Works great for that. Only thing it has now done is mess up some further row filtering I had - with checkboxes. I really am struggling to understand how to get everything to work together! Any help would be really appreciated, thank you

Comment: Can you provide details about the other filters...a js fiddle with all the filters would be great!

Comment: How do I add a js fiddle now? As an answer?

Comment: The script for the checkboxes is already in the question - the html is here: <section id="type">

  <p id="Mortgage Type">Mortgage Type</p>
  <input type="checkbox" name="type" value="t2" id="t2" checked/>2yr Fixed<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="type" value="t3" id="t3" checked/>3yr Fixed<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="type" value="t5" id="t5" checked/>5yr Fixed<br>

</section>

<section id="fee">

  <p id="Fee">Fee</p>
  <input type="checkbox" name="fee" value="fee" id="fee" checked/>Fee<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="fee" value="nofee" id="nofee" checked/>No Fee<br>

</section>

Comment: Either you can edit your question and add relevant code (I don't think there are any checkbox in the current code) or you can go to jsFiddle.net add your html and js there and just share the link here

Comment: Ah okay, sorry two seconds.

Comment: No problemo! One more clarification: From the js - it looks like there are two checkbox with ids 'type' and 'fee'. So which row should become visible when 'type' is selected and which one when 'fee' is selected

Comment: The rows in the table should filter so that they only show when both sections of checkboxes and the LTV fall within the <tr> values for the right <td class>. I can get either one of the three form inputs to work now, but cannot tie them together? Checkbox html added to original question now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91013/discussion-between-taleeb-and-j-ayo).

Comment: See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/taleebanwar/a6oe6j4r/3/). Let me know if it works/does not work for you

Comment: Thank you, that worked perfectly (except for the less/greater than needed swapping!)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand all of your code, but in general it could be done like this:

```
//For every tr in the table.
$("#mortagetable tr").each(function() {
     //I assume that the variable loantovalue is defiend globally somewhere,
     //since I can not understand how it is supposed to be calculated from your question.
     //Get the number from the right td.
     var x = parseInt($(this).find(".ltv").text())
     //Toggel the visibility of this tr.
     $(this).toggle(loantovalue > x);
});
```

*Disclaimar: I have not tested this code.*